# How can I unregister a Collection in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, meteor

I am trying to implement simple functionality to allow a Meteor app to check whether a certain MongoDB string can be successfully used for a connection. In order to do so I have an event trigger a server method that establishes a connection to the MongoDB and returns the number of docs inside the collection.
The (simplified) method I am using takes the mongo connection string and a collection name and returns the number of docs inside the collection.

```js
var mongoUrl = "mongodb://user:password@192.168.0.98:27017/mydb";
var collectionName = "test";

Meteor.methods({
  testDbConnection: function(mongoUrl, collectionName) {
    var database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(mongoUrl);
    TestCollection = new Mongo.Collection(collectionName, { _driver: database });
    var numberOfDocs = TestCollection.find().count();
    // HELP: how to unregister TestCollection?
    return numberOfDocs;
  }
});
```

The first call of the method works, but because I have not unregistered `TestCollection` all subsequent calls fail, because Meteor already has an `insert` method for the `test` collection defined.

```
Exception while invoking method 'testDbConnection' Error: A method named '/test/insert' is already defined
       at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1444:1
       at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
       at [object Object]._.extend.methods (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1442:1)
       at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._defineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:886:1)
       at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:208:1)
       at [object Object].Meteor.methods.testDbConnection (app/app.js:55:24)
       at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1599:1)
       at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
       at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
       at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
```

How can I unregister a Collection in Meteor in order to perform these ad hoc database connections?

Comment: Since creating a `Collection` does more than just provide an interface to the mongo collection, aren't you better off just using  `MongoInternals` or the npm `mongodb` for those simple ad-hoc queries?

Comment: In fact, it does work nicely using 
`var numberOfDocs = database.open(collectionName).find().count();` But to me the question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I haven't got an answer to your direct question, I have an idea that might help in your quest!

I would consider using a "worker" approach, which is your Meteor app that performs a single task and dies. Then you need not worry about clean-up.

- If using Velocity, You could start a "self-destructing mirror". You can start it [like this](https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-cucumber/blob/distributed/src/server-master.js#L74) and kill the mirror [like this](https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-cucumber/blob/distributed/src/server-mirror.js#L195).
- You can still use the same approach above if you're not using Velocity by forking a child_process from your main app to start `.meteor/.../build/main.js`

You can tell your app it's in worker-mode by passing the child_process an environment variable.

Side note: Ever since we (the velocity team) did this for mirrors, I've been considering writing a Meteor worker package that does the above.